# Shared Screens between React-Navigation Tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am having trouble trying to come up with how to set up my navigators for when I want to be able to navigate to the same page from different tabs. For example:

Discover/Search Tab: I want to be able to click and link and navigate to a Product Screen with that being placed on top of the stack.

Feed Tab: I want to be able to click a link to a product and navigate to the Product Screen with that being placed on top of the stack.

Most of the examples I have seen have StackNavigators nested within the TabNavigator. Would I have a StackNavigator nested in both so that both navigate to the same screen? This duplication seems a little odd. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can nest your TabNavigator inside a StackNavigator. This way you can navigate to different screens within the stack from any tab you like. But this method result with when you navigate on a new screen you can see the tabs from the TabNavigator.